# Why do plants flap their leaves?

Tags: botany

Simple question really, I have a plant, that I'm not sure of the species. Every few days I watch its leaves droop (which scares me because I worry the plant has died), but then a few days later I find it's perked right back up. Then a few days later it does the same thing again. I don't think it's dying, in nature documentaries with time lapse I've seen plants do similar things while growing and I was curious what it's called, and why they do it?

It kind of looks like the plants are flapping their leaves, one day they're hanging down drooping, the next they're up in the air.

#### Photos

There's more to come, but here's a photo of what it looks like right now

[image: my pretty plant]

##### Update

I've got a timelapse here I took frames once every hour, for about a week.

https://youtu.be/VE_D3E_Mioc

Two days ago the big leaves were dropping down the sides of the pot

Comment: Are you observing your plant at the same time every day? Does it receive enough water daily? How stable is it's environment (temperature, humidity, sunlight, etc.)? A plants leaves can droop and wilt when they don't have enough water, and they will perk up again when they are watered, possibly explaining the movement you described. They can also respond to environmental stimuli. These responses are known as tropisms. For example, plants that grow towards a light source exhibit phototropism.

Comment: I observe it regularly in the morning and the evening, I water it every week. But if I water when it starts wilting, then it just keeps wilting, it seems to wilt and perk up on a regular interval of every week or so.

Comment: The environment is pretty stable around 70 degrees, same with the humidity, I think. It sits in the window in my dorm room. It gets sunlight for a few hours every day, less than I think I'd like to give it, but it's the best I can do given my limitations of the dorm. Does that help @MikeyC

Comment: watch sped up footage of plants growing.

Comment: I know, that's what I'm asking about, so you've seen it then? What's it called? @John

Comment: this may be helpful https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33888615/

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Can you add pictures of your plant over time (from the same position) showing the "flapping" and more detail about the pattern/timing? For example, is there any correlation with bright vs. dark days or outside temperature (might be relevant if it is right next to a poorly insulated window)? In general, these sound like ["Nastic movements"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nastic_movements), but the time scale seems slower than I would expect.

Comment: @tyersome I can try to start doing that, but I haven't been taking any pictures up to this point, I will add pictures once I get them taken

Comment: @tyersome I added a photo of what my plant looks like right now

Comment: hi @iggy12345 you can take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliotropism and here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phototropism i know too little about this to make an answer.

Comment: Terms to investigate: Water pressures + wilting + water regulation

Comment: @theforestecologist I think that's what's happening, but I added a timelapse, just in case, if you add that as an answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Strongly agree with all of what @bob1 wrote. In addition, that pot looks like the type of container that is terrible for plants because it has no drainage and also doesn't breathe — this usually results in excess moisture accumulating at the bottom after watering leading to root rot. If you really like the container, I encourage you to put your *Coleus* into a separate pot (preferably an unglazed ceramic) with a drainage hole. You can then display your plant as you like, but pull out the inner pot to drain off the excess water.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having looked at the time-lapse:

I suspect you might get a better answer out of gardening on this one, but I think it is entirely water related and that you are underwatering or watering poorly. It could also be that there is some problem with the pot - it may not be draining properly and the water is pooling in the bottom, which can cause root rotting.

What happens when you let a pot dry out is that when you add water, it takes some time for the soil/potting mix in the pot to hydrate. In fact, the potting mix can even become hydrophobic, so even though you see water flowing through the pot, it isn't actually soaking in.

Water won't be taken up immediately, it takes some time to soak into the potting mix, and then be taken up by the roots and transported to the leaves.

If the pot has holes in the bottom, try soaking the pot in water from the bottom once a week (I suggest about 1h - stand it in a tray), rather than adding water to the top, and/or more regular watering.

The plant you have is a *[Coleus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleus)*, which are good pot plants. They do, however need regular watering, about every 2-3 days and good drainage to do their best. There is a good guide to growing them at [TheSpruce.com](https://www.thespruce.com/how-to-grow-coleus-plants-1402921).

I would say, the pale colour of the leaves is an indicator that it is suffering in some manner. There are a few possible causes - it possibly needs a bit more sun, but the few hours in your window should be enough. Having said that, the pale colour could also be from nutrient deficiency, particularly nitrogen, or caused by being too dry. The dry edges/tips on the leaves also indicate that it has been too dry at some point in the past few months.